# jwt auth laravel 5 gives error The token could not be parsed from the request

Tags: angularjs, laravel, authentication, jwt, json-web-token

I've set up a frontend angular system and backend laravel system. Everything is working well but the tokens aren't being generated in login process. The registration process works well and stores the users details in the database.

Routes.php

```
Route::post('/api/register', 'RegisterController@register');
Route::post('api/authenticate', 'LoginController@authenticate');
Route::get('api/authenticate/user/email/{email}/password/{password}', 'LoginController@getAuthenticatedUser');
```

RegisterController.php

```
 public function register(Request $request){
    $newuser= $request->all();
    $password=Hash::make($request->input('password'));

    $newuser['password'] = $password;
    return Register::create($newuser);
}
```

LoginController.php

```
/*public function authenticate(Request $request){*/
public function authenticate($email, $password){
    /*$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');*/
    $credentials = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);
    try{
        if(! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
            return \Response::json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    }
    catch(JWTException $e){
        return \Response::json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }
    return \Response::json(compact('token'));
}


public function getAuthenticatedUser($email, $password){
    try{
        if(! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate($email, $password)){
            return \Response::json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e){
        return \Response::json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e){
        return \Response::json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e){
        return \Response::json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    return \Response::json(compact('user'));
    /*return \Response::json(array('user' => 'Steve', 'state' => 'CA'));*/
}
```

authController.js

```
reglogApp.controller('AuthController', function($scope, $http, $auth, $rootScope, $state){
$scope.email='';
$scope.password='';
$scope.newUser={};
$scope.loginError=false;
$scope.loginErrorText='';


$scope.login = function(){
    var credentials = {
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
    }
    console.log('Entered Login Function', credentials);

    $auth.login(credentials).then(function(){
        return $http.get('http://reglog.xyz.com/api/authenticate/user/email/puppy@gmail.com/password/ABHVF123456789000');

        },function(error){
            $scope.loginError = true;
            $scope.loginErrorText = error.data.error;
            console.log('Login Error', $scope.loginErrorText);
        }).then(function(response){
                $rootScope.currentUser = response.data.user;
                $scope.loginError = false;
                $scope.loginErrorText = '';
                console.log('Current User', $rootScope.currentUser);
                $state.go('dashboard');
        });

}

$scope.register = function(){
    $scope.name = $scope.newUser.name;
    $scope.email = $scope.newUser.email;
    $scope.password = $scope.newUser.password;
    console.log($scope.name, $scope.email, $scope.password);
    $http.post('http://reglog.xyz.com/api/register', $scope.newUser).success(function(data){
        console.log('Registered');
        $scope.email = $scope.newUser.email;
        $scope.password = $scope.newUser.password;
        $scope.login();
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Are you passing a CSRF token?

Comment: no, I've commented the line in kernal.php

Answer (score 4):

You need to send authorization token in the header.
You might need to modify your Apache settings to allow for authorization headers to be sent.

**Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere}**

You can modify your .htaccess file with:

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)

RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

Answer (score 3):

`JWTAuth::parseToken()` requires token to be sent in the header in the following format:

```
Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere}
```

And I believe, you don't do that. So, your `getAuthenticatedUser` fails.

Comment: could you elaborate, didn't get you. Are you saying I need to make changes to LoginController.php file.

Comment: @StacyJ I'm saying, that this is not Laravel, that throws an exception and this exception is not about CSRF token which check you removed from Kernel. This exception comes from JWT library, which expects you to send JWT token in the request header.

Comment: Yes I had checked JWTAuth.php and saw the error message. But I am not sure what to do next in order to rectify this.

Comment: @StacyJ Send token in the request header.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to set always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 in php.ini

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `LoginController::getAuthenticatedUser()` seems like to authenticate a user's credentials (email and password).

However, there is also `JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate($email, $password)` in the `getAuthenticatedUser()` method. The `JWTAuth::parseToken()` is responsible for validating the token from request [1](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/master/src/JWTAuth.php#L185). The client MUST send a request to the *GET /api/authenticate* endpoint with the token.

In my opinion, the `LoginController::authenticate()` identifies and responses user's information to client by JSON Web Token. The `email` and `password` parameters are NOT necessary in `LoginController:: getAuthenticatedUser()`, because the token is able to identify a user.

*LoginController.php*

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser(){
    try{
        if(! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()){
            return \Response::json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e){
        return \Response::json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e){
        return \Response::json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e){
        return \Response::json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    return \Response::json(compact('user'));
    /*return \Response::json(array('user' => 'Steve', 'state' => 'CA'));*/
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple edit .htaccess file. i.e., inside /public/.htaccess

---

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: How does an .htaccess file address the problem?